# How to query a DocumentReference in Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a collection of bar orders, and in each document i have a field with a reference for a barman.

[image: Illustrative image]

---

I'm trying to made a where with the doc reference.

Something like that:

```
orders = this.database.collection("orders",
    (ref) => ref.where("barman.path", "==", "barmen/" + this.auth.auth.currentUser.uid),
);
return orders.valueChanges();
```

`barman.path` because when i get a doc with a field referece, this is the way to get the reference path.

I already tried to use just `barman` instead `barman.path`.

I already tried to made where with full 'path' of docref (`firestore.googleapis.com/pro...`).

Any ideas?

Put only the id instead of the full reference will dificult other parts of the system.

Answer (score 1):

In order to query a reference field, you should create a `DocumentReference` object that matches the location you are trying to query for, and use that.  Note that this needs to be a native Firestore reference, as an `AngularFirestoreCollection` and `AngularFirestoreDocument` will just show up to Firestore as a "custom object type".  You can get this with the `ref` member of the AngularFirestore types.

I'm not sure where the '.path' part of your query is coming form, as the actual field you are querying for is `barman`.  I've removed it in the example.

In your case, this will look something like:

```js
const queryReference = this.database
    .collection('barmen')
    .doc(this.auth.auth.currentUser.uid).ref;

orders = this.database.collection('orders',
    (ref) => ref.where('barman', '==', queryReference),
);
return orders.valueChanges();
```

I obviously couldn't test this exactly as there isn't enough code to, for example, show that `this.auth.auth.currentUser.uid` works in this case.  But it should point you in the right direction.